# How to wait for AJAX success handler to finish executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am returning an object within my AJAX success handler, which I `need` before my code executes any further. However, when using AJAX, it does not wait for the success block to finish executing, and hence printing the value as of `myLayer` variable as `undefined` as the `console.log(mylayer)` line gets executed before a value is returned by the success handler. How can I wait for the success handler to return the `userLayer` object so that the `myLayer` value is not `undefined`?

P.S. no need to worry about how the datatype and definition of `myLayer` and `userLayer` variables, as they are correct in my code and are taken care of. Didn't include it here so as to keep the question simple and to the point. I've been stuck on this problem for really long. Any help will be deeply appreciated :)

**Calling the AJAX function**

```
myLayer = this.addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer);
          
// This always prints "undefined" as it gets executed before the AJAX
// success handler returns the value
console.log(myLayer)
```

**Defining the AJAX function**

```
addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer) {
 
  let configData = {"searchText": "search", "searchType" : "treemail"};

  $.ajax({
    url: "../apis/mySearch",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : configData,
    success: response => {

      userLayer.query().where(response).run((data) => {
          userLayer.add(data);
      });

       // I need this object to be stored in the myLayer variable (when calling the 
      // function above) after the success handler of AJAX function is executed. 
     // Currently, it only returns this variable after console.log(myLayer) above 
    // which yields in the myLayer variable to print "undefined".
       console.log(userLayer);
       return userLayer;
            }
      });
    }
```

Comment: simply you can try this:    myLayer = this.addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer).then(function() {
 console.log(myLayer)
});;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can promisify ajax call by wrapping it in `Promise`. e.g

```
  async function addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer) {
  let configData = { searchText: "search", searchType: "treemail" };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../apis/mySearch",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: configData,
      success: (response) => {
        userLayer
          .query()
          .where(response)
          .run((data) => {
            userLayer.add(data);
          });
        resolve(userLayer);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        reject(error);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

And then you can consume data by using code below:

```
async function print() {
  try {
    myLayer = await this.addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer);
    console.log(myLayer)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

print()
```

Comment: thanks for the response, where are we returning the `userLayer` in this case?

Comment: this line is doing the magic. `resolve(data);`. basically it would return data to calling function.

Comment: I do not want to return `data`. I want to return `userLayer` value and store it in `myLayer` variable

Comment: Even though it does not print 'undefined', it still does not work as expected. As for debugging purposes, it prints - `Promise {<pending>}`

Comment: `myLayer = await this.addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer);` are you using await keyword and these lines must be in async function

Comment: I have modified the answer that will return userLayer.

Comment: I just checked my terminal - it gives an error - `await is a reserved word (1101:24)` when executing this line - `myLayer = await this.addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer)`

Comment: This is Promise constructor antipattern. "$.ajax" itself is Promise. No need to create external Promise around it.

Comment: ajax() function returns the XMLHttpRequest object that it creates. It does not return Promise.

Comment: @IanBell You cannnot use await keyword in global space. I have modified the above snippet. You can check now.

Answer (score 2):

You can get get async code look like sync code by using "async" and "await".
Use keyword "await" at when you need returned value of async function.

If function uses "await" it must have "async" keyword before function definition

```
async addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer) {

    let configData = {"searchText": "search", "searchType" : "treemail"};

    var response = await $.ajax({
        url: "../apis/mySearch",
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : configData,
    });
      
      
    userLayer.query().where(response).run((data) => {
        userLayer.add(data);
    });

    console.log(userLayer);
    return userLayer;
}
```

Don't forget to add "async" in parent script

```
async function main(userLayer){
    myLayer = await this.addUserLayerTreemail(userLayer);
          
    console.log(myLayer)
}
```